# This .mpg video clip doesn't play well

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, codec, mpg

I've installed K-lite mega codec pack v6.9.0 with playback essentials without player.
My default and only media player is windows media player.
here are the clip's media info:

```
General
Complete name                    : D:\Users\Roey\Downloads\B384MV.mpg
Format                           : MPEG-PS
File size                        : 273 MiB
Duration                         : 4mn 59s
Overall bit rate                 : 7 643 Kbps

Video
ID                               : 224 (0xE0)
Format                           : MPEG Video
Format version                   : Version 2
Format profile                   : Main@High
Format settings, BVOP            : No
Format settings, Matrix          : Default
Format settings, GOP             : M=1, N=15
Duration                         : 4mn 57s
Bit rate mode                    : Variable
Bit rate                         : 7 363 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                 : 9 000 Kbps
Width                            : 1 920 pixels
Height                           : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 16:9
Frame rate                       : 25.000 fps
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Compression mode                 : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.142
Stream size                      : 261 MiB (96%)

Audio
ID                               : 192 (0xC0)
Format                           : MPEG Audio
Format version                   : Version 1
Format profile                   : Layer 3
Mode                             : Joint stereo
Duration                         : 4mn 59s
Bit rate mode                    : Constant
Bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 2 channels
Sampling rate                    : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                 : Lossy
Stream size                      : 4.56 MiB (2%)

Menu
```

When I play it there is no sound (just a little "kahhhh" noise every 10-20 seconds) and the frames are moving very slow - it "jumps" frames.
A blue tray icon [FFa] "ffdshow audio decoder" pops with the following details:

```
Input:MP3, stereo, 44100 Hz (libavocodec)
Output:PCM, stereo, 44100 Hz, 16-bit integer
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My advice is get rid of K-Lite altogether

Or any codec pack for that matter

Also, ditch Windows Media Player as well.

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) are much better alternatives.

If either of them won't play your format with it's built in filters then simply adding [ffdshow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) should enable them to.

With codecs less is always better - only install what you need

Answer (score 0):

Try running the MPG through [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) (no really its a real app!)
It will tell you advanced information about the file.  If all else fails, [download VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and see if it *repairs* the file.  You could have a damaged file.

Good luck.

Comment: Gspot hasn't been updated in 4 years. MediaInfo is a much better and still maintained alternative: http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

That bitrate is extremely high (7 megabits/second).  Depending on your system, that could be the problem right there.  VLC (as mentioned by Jakub) or programs like ffmpeg can reduce that.

Are you sure the file is not just corrupted?  Can you edit your post to include a link to it on the Internet somewhere? (You can upload any random video to YouTube free.)

Actually, uploading to YouTube might be interesting--they convert the file to both FLV and MP4 formats.  If the uploaded/converted version is playable you know the original file is valid.

Comment: that bitrate is not high at all - MP@HL can handle up to 80 Mbit/s (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.262/MPEG-2_Part_2#Video_profiles_and_levels)

Comment: if anything, its too low: for 1920x1080 @ 7363 kbit/s @ 25fps the bits per pixel is only 0.14... should be at least 0.15 if not 0.2

Comment: High for web video, I guess.  Not high in an absolute sense, thanks for clarifying. It's certainly too high for at least two of the PCs I own to play ....